# Finding the MGF of a distribution given it depends on another distribution?

Tags: moment-generating-functions

So my question told me to find the $E[Y]$ and $V[Y]$ first and then find the PGF of $Y$ and state its distribution. Am I supposed to use the information from $E[Y]$ and $E[X]$ to derive the PGF or are they unrelated, because I am having trouble finding the PGF of $Y$.

Let $ X \sim exp(1) $ and $Y  |X = x \sim Pn(x)$

From: $$E[E[Y|X=x]] = E[Y]$$
$$ E[X] = E[Y] $$
Since:
$$E[X] = 1 $$
So I found that: $$E[Y] = E[X] = 1$$
and:
$$V[Y] = E[V[Y|X]] +V[E[Y|X]]$$
$$V[Y] = E[X] + E[Y] = 2$$

And this is where I am stuck I don't know how to find the PGF of $Y$

Answer (score 1):

MGF of $Y$ is ${\mathbb E} e^{tY}$. To find it, you may use the formula you cited,

$${\mathbb E} e^{tY} = \sum_x {\mathbb E} (e^{tY} | X=x) P(X=x) $$

EDIT: I notice that you actually wanted PGF, not MGF. Also, $X$ has a continuous distribution. So, the above formula modifies to

$${\mathbb E} z^Y = \int {\mathbb E} (z^Y | X=x) f(x) dx $$

Comment: So I would have to find the MGF of Y first and then use the MGF of Y to derive the PGF of Y?